# Resolving: SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl, https

Full trace of my exception is:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: 
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

First of all I'd like to say that I know that it's very common exception, and I tried to apply different solutions, I'll describe them later, but nothing help me.

So, I have two instances of tomcat 7 on same machine. Directly speaking, these instances have each own `CATALINA_BASE` directory, but common `CATALINA_HOME`. Also they are isolated - ports configured so that instances don't interfere. One instance - server - with deployed web application, servlet. And another instance for client - servlet too.

This is fragment of server.xml of server tomcat:

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
        maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
        clientAuth="true" sslProtocol="TLS" 
        truststoreFile="C:/Users/dpivovar/ssl_server.jks" 
        truststorePass="start123"
        keystoreFile="C:/Users/dpivovar/ssl_server.jks" 
        keystorePass="start123"/>
```

And this fragment of client tomcat:

```
<Connector port="8444" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
        maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
        clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" 
        truststoreFile="C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_45/jre/lib/security/cacerts" 
        truststorePass="changeit"
        keystoreFile="C:/Users/dpivovar/ssl_client.jks" 
        keystorePass="start123" />
```

Work flow: client make attempt to do GET to the server, but it gets exception described above.

What about certificates. I used java keytool. I made `one keystore for server and separate for client`. Each keystore contains `private key` and `public certificate` of corresponding side. In above example client truststore refere to the jre cacerts keystore, because one of solution i found was to put public certificate of server to the jre cacerts. but it doesn't work for me. 
Another solution i found (http://www.nodsw.com/blog/leeland/2006/12/06-no-more-unable-find-valid-certification-path-requested-target) offers via InstallCert tool to get an public certificate of server and then use it in client truststore. So now, in jre caserts there is a public certificate of server but exception is raised.
Also, i have a simple client example - it's plain java program, through system property i set required paths to keystores, which i use for client, and in the same way i make GET to the server and it works, handshake occured, connection established.

So can you help me, what can be wrong, what prevents client which is deployed on tomcat to establish ssl connection with server?

Comment: any [help](http://ankursinghal86.blogspot.in/2014/06/authentication-with-client-certificate.html)

Comment: Use `openssl s_client` to test the setup. Please post the output of `s_client` as part of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this issue by setting in tomcat configuration system Java properties for keystore/truststore and keystorePassword/truststorePassword.

Answer (score 2):

```
    truststoreFile="C:/Users/dpivovar/ssl_server.jks" 
    truststorePass="start123"
```

These attributes do not exist. You have to set them via the system properties.